# Angular 7/Ionic 4 - background-image url path problem

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass

So I have a problem on the windows universal platform where background-image will never display. This works fine for Android, iOS and browsers in general.

This is an angular 7 / Ionic 4 project.
In an scss file I reference an image this way:

```
background-image: url('/assets/img/image.png');
```

But the Windows universal platform will not work unless I set:

```
background-image: url('./assets/img/image.png');
```

or

```
background-image: url('assets/img/image.png');
```

What works for Windows does not for the rest.
Any solution to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I devised a workaround that works for me. Basically I'm using a before_compile hook for windows only. Here's the hook if anyone wonders:

```
module.exports = function (ctx) {

  var fs = ctx.requireCordovaModule('fs'),
    path = ctx.requireCordovaModule('path');

  var init = function(){
    console.log("Changing image path for Windows.");

    var filePath = path.join(ctx.opts.projectRoot + '/platforms/windows/www/');

    console.log("List of modified files: ");
    fs.readdirSync(filePath).forEach(file => {
      transformFile(filePath + file);
    });
  };


  var transformFile = function(filePath) {

    fs.stat(filePath, function (error, stat) {

      if (error || stat.isDirectory() ) {
          return;
      }

      var data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');

      if(data.indexOf('/assets/img') >= 0) {

        console.log(filePath);
        var result = data.replace(/\/assets\/img\//g,'assets/img/')

        fs.writeFileSync(filePath, result, 'utf8');
      }
    });
  };

  init();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

did you also try

background-image: url('../../assets/img/image.png');

Comment: Does not compile

Answer (score 0):

Try giving an absolute path instead of relative.

Instead of `background-image: url('./assets/img/image.png');`

Use `background-image: url('https://your-domain-name/assets/img/image.png');`

> e.g.
>
> If you are running on localhost:4200 then your code will be
>
> `background-image: url('https://localhost:4200/assets/img/image.png');`

Let me know if it is working for you, Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, since this is running on devices through cordova, I doubt this would work consistently. What would be the address?

Comment: Try accessing your image in assets folder from the browser on windows. Go to `https://your-domain-name/assets/img/image.png`.

Comment: There is no webserver running outside of the application itself. When I transpiled with ionic/angular, I see the result assets in the right folders. The same build works for Android/iOS, even the Edge browser when using "ionic serve". It's only windows universal that seems to be looking at the wrong place

Comment: There is a workaround. Put this in your code `background-image: url('/assets/img/image.png'),url('./assets/img/image.png');`

Comment: I tried that and it will not compile :( I made a workaround using a hook where I manually change the paths I find with this for Windows only.